# Set Userfield to allow Multiple using pnp in SharePoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-framework, pnp-powershell, pnp

I've Created a Field on my list `PollAnswers` and everything works fine with that part:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("PollAnswers").fields.
addUser("Users", FieldUserSelectionMode.PeopleOnly).then(() => {
```

But I'm unable to allow it to set Multiple Values to true doing the creating process of the field:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("PollAnswers").fields.
addUser("Users", FieldUserSelectionMode.PeopleOnly,{"mult":true}).then(() => {
```

I know `{"mult":true}` is the problem, but I can't figure out what to write to set the user field as multiple.

Does someone know what the correct way to set the Field as Allow Multiple Values, on a User field in SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify `{"mult":true}` to `{"AllowMultipleValues":true}`.

So, your code will be as below:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("PollAnswers").fields.
addUser("Users", FieldUserSelectionMode.PeopleOnly,{"AllowMultipleValues":true}).
then(() => {
  //do some stuff
});
```

It is based on the [FieldUser properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fielduser_properties.aspx).